# Simple pivot table type transformation in R statistics

Tags: r

I've been trying learn R for a while but haven't got my knowledge up to even a decent level yet. I'll get there in the end, but I'm in a pinch at the moment and was wondering if you could help me do a quick "transformation" type piece.

I have a csv data file with 18 million rows with the following data fields: Person ID, Date and Value. It's basically from a simulation model and is simulating the contributions a person makes into their savings accounts, e.g.:

```
1,28/02/2013,19.49
2,13/03/2013,16.68
3,15/03/2013,20.34
2,10/01/2014,28.43
3,12/06/2014,38.13
1,29/08/2014,68.46
1,20/12/2013,20.51
```

So, as you can see, there can be multiple IDs in the data but each date and contribution amount for a person is unique.

I would like to transform this so I have a contribution history by year for each person. So for example the above would become:

```
ID,2013,2014
1,40.00,68.46
2,16.68,28.43
3,20.34,38.13
```

I have a rough idea how I could approach the problem: create another column of data with just the years and then summarise by ID and year to add up all contributions that fit into each ID/year bucket. I just have no clue how to even begin translating that into an R script.

Any pointers/guidance would be most appreciated.

Many Thanks and Kind Regards.

Comment: with 18 million rows you almost certainly want to look into `data.table` solutions (for reading in the data as well as for reshaping)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a few possibilities:

**zoo package** `read.zoo` in the [zoo package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) can produce a multivariate time series one column per series, i.e. one column per ID.  We define `yr` to get the year from the index column and then split on the ID using the `split=` argument as we read it in.  We use `aggregate=sum` to aggregate over the remaining columns -- here just one.  We use text = Lines to keep the code below  self contained but with a real file we would replace that with `"myfile"`, say.  The final line transposes the result. We could drop that line if it were OK to have persons in columns instead of rows.

```
Lines <- "1,28/02/2013,19.49
2,13/03/2013,16.68
3,15/03/2013,20.34
2,10/01/2014,28.43
3,12/06/2014,38.13
1,29/08/2014,68.46
1,20/12/2013,20.51
"
library(zoo)

# given a Date string, x, output the year
yr <- function(x) floor(as.numeric(as.yearmon(x, "%d/%m/%Y")))

# read in data, reshape & aggregate
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, sep = ",", index = 2, FUN = yr,  
   aggregate = sum, split = 1)     

# transpose (optional)  
tz <- data.frame(ID = colnames(z), t(z), check.names = FALSE)
```

With the posted data we get the following result:

```
> tz
  ID  2013  2014
1  1 40.00 68.46
2  2 16.68 28.43
3  3 20.34 38.13
```

See `?read.zoo` and also the `zoo-read` vignette.

**reshape2 package** Here is a second solution using the reshape2 package:

```
library(reshape2)

# read in and fix up column names and Year

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, sep = ",") ##
colnames(DF) <- c("ID", "Year", "Value") ##
DF$Year <- sub(".*/", "", DF$Year) ##

dcast(DF, ID ~ Year, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "Value")
```

The result is:

```
  ID  2013  2014
1  1 40.00 68.46
2  2 16.68 28.43
3  3 20.34 38.13
```

**reshape function** Here is a solution that does not use any addon packages.  First read in the data using the three lines marked ## in the last solution.  This will produce `DF`.  Then aggregate the data, reshape it from long to wide form and finally fix up the column names:

```
Ag <- aggregate(Value ~., DF, sum)
res <- reshape(Ag, direction = "wide", idvar = "ID", timevar = "Year")
colnames(res) <- sub("Value.", "", colnames(res))
```

which produces this:

```
> res
  ID  2013  2014
1  1 40.00 68.46
2  2 16.68 28.43
3  3 20.34 38.13
```

**tapply function**. This solution does not use addon packages either.  Using `Ag` from the last solution try this:

```
tapply(Ag$Value, Ag[1:2], sum)
```

UPDATES: minor improvements and 3 additional solutions.

Comment: Fabulous work there Mr Grothendieck. Solution 2 has worked well. Solution 1 (zoo package) kind of worked but then it seemed to give multiple IDs prefixed with v3. and v4. Again, my knowledge on R is weak so not entirely sure if this is an issue with my data or the code. The second solution (using the reshape2 package) worked perfectly. I've only run it a few times but I'll go away and test it and run it on the main dataset. Thank you again. This has been exceptionally helpful. It's also nice to see there is a solution (solution 3) that has the elegance of sticking to the base function  :)

Comment: Would need something reproducible to comment. Perhaps you can prepare a small data set that illustrates it as there is no v3/v4 in the reproducible example shown in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The approach you describe is a sound one. Translating the date string back and forth from string to date and back can be done using `strptime` and `strftime` (possible `as.POSIXct`. Once you have the `year` column, you can use a number of tools available in R, e.g. `data.table`, `by`, or `ddply`. I like the syntax of the last one:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(ID, year), summarise, total_per_year = sum(value))
```

This assumes that your base date is in `df`, and that the columns in your data are called `year`, `ID` and `value`. Do note that for large datasets `ddply` can become quite slow. If you really need raw performance, you definitely want to start working with `data.table`.

Comment: Very good and "almost" got there. Thank you Paul. It turns out I didn't have the plyr package installed so for anyone coming this afterward please make sure you install the "plyr" package from "Packages > Install packages" menu. So now the only thing missing is to make each year a separate column. I'm now going to try Mr Grothendieck's answer using the zoo package too and see how that fairs. Thank again.

Comment: @TylerDurden Sorry for not mentioning that, I'll add it to my answer.